# Exception handling in Paypal checkout where not able to access id of iframe element

Tags: selenium

I have an eCommerce website where, when I try to place an Order where it redirects to a Paypal Page. When I Login as a Paypal user, it redirects to another checkout screen where I try to automate using selenium web driver.

At this step, I get the following exception (I tried to access the iframe by using Println method):

Chrome Version Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)
    Selenium Server Standalone jar:3.9.1

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\MVN020\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1759291335\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 39463
Only local connections are allowed.
size3
size3
size1
FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'GOKAL', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_40'
Session ID: 4b02279f3819eced46aa69a5c4f37004
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\MVN020\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir12284_24522, chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f)}, networkConnectionEnabled=false, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, rotatable=false, setWindowRect=true, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=64.0.3282.140, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, hasTouchScreen=false, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:857)
    at automationFramework.CodePaypal.f(CodePaypal.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@143f45a8: 22 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@7595edfe: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 5 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1b814a5: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@7aee64f1: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3ed9a7a6: 15 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situations problem might be one of the two below reasons.

1.If its redirecting to new window and without switching to new window you cannot access any locator of new window. You can use the below code to switch window

```
 String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
 //Get Parent window handle befor child window opens
 String winHandleBefore = _driver.getWindowHandle();
 for (String winHandle : _driver.getWindowHandles()) {
   // Switch to child window
   if( Parent_Window != winHandle )
   driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 }
```

Perform the action in child window and switch back to parent window.

2. If it is not redirecting to new window and your locator is correct then the problem might be that , frame you are looking for is the child of some other frame. In that case you may have to switch to parent frame first and then to child frame.

Hope this will work.