# Selenium : handling popups

Tags: selenium, testing, browser, automation

I'm getting an error while handling default popups with selenium scripts.

Here is the Code :

```
@Test
public void handlePop() {

    WebElement pop1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupCTRLMain_imgNext']"));
    pop1.click();

    WebElement pop2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupCTRLMain_Image2']"));
    pop2.click();
}
```

Following is the error I am getting while running the code:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupCTRLMain_Image2']
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PopupCTRLMain_Image2']

Comment: That means that your element can not be found. Have you opened the developer tools in your browser and searched for that element?

Comment: yes, I tried. I also tried with other options like with cssPath, htmlPath

Comment: Actually, the scenario is like two different popups are there, by clicking next button of the first popup I am jumping to another one. at that time I am getting this error

Comment: hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736196/selenium-based-scraping-code-fails-with-the-error-nosuchelementexception/48761092#48761092

Comment: More than likely your code is executing too quickly, it's clicking the first popup button, but you have no delay between that and the second popup click, I would wait until the second popup button is there before trying to click it.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707886/exception-handling-in-paypal-checkout-where-not-able-to-access-id-of-iframe-elem/48709719#48709719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably add if condition to check if the pop is displayed, like

```
try { 
if (pop1.getSize > 0) {
  pop1.click();
 } catch (e)
}
```