# Selenium alert no html

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I have an issue with an alert/popup. When I enter my login info, I am redirected to this page https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhmDW.jpg. 
Once I reach this page, I would like to accept the Alert, but I cant use SwitchTo().Alert, because i get the error "no alert open".
If I manually press the return button, I can accept the alert, but if I use SendKeys(Keys.Return) it has no effect. I've tried waiting for the entire page to load aswell, but it's still not working. 
As it shows on the picture, I cant find any elements at all, so I have no idea where to go from here. Has anyone encountered this issue before or maybe have a fix?

Comment: this might help you , https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709719/7877196

Comment: Seems to be a _Modal Dialog Box_. Try to locate the element within the _HTML DOM_

Comment: Which kind of alert is this ? a web based generated ?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit occupied yesterday. To be honest, I'm not quite sure. I press a button and am redirected to the paged that I linked above. Nothing is shown in developer tools